# remove old SSRS Schedule jobs

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs

We have a application that creates SSRS Schedules 2 times a year and it does create one for each of our customers.

Each schedulation results in a SQL Agent job with a GUID as name and the description `This job is owned by a report server process. Modifying this job could result in database incompatibilities. Use Report Manager or Management Studio to update this job.`.

The schedulations just run one time and then just collects dust.

Is there any way to remove all old jobs and information about the schedulations in the SSRS database?

Comment: You can use the script to [identify a scheduled SQL Server Reporting Services report](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1846/how-to-easily-identify-a-scheduled-sql-server-reporting-services-report/) and then check the last run time and then first disable those jobs and then delete them if no one screams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem.
Create the following files:

RemoveSubscriptions.bat:

```
@echo OFF
SET Server=http://localhost/ReportServer_MSSQL_2008
SET ReportUrl=/test/reports/testreport
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\rs.exe" -i RemoveSubscriptions.rss -s %Server% -e Mgmt2010 -v reportUrl=%ReportUrl% > %date%.log
```

RemoveSubscriptions.rss:

```
Public Sub Main()
    rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
    Dim subscriptions as Subscription() = rs.ListSubscriptions(reportUrl)
    For Each item As Subscription in subscriptions
        'Delete all subscriptions that are older then one month
        If (item.LastExecutedSpecified AndAlso item.LastExecuted.AddMonths(1) < Date.Now) Then
            Console.WriteLine("Removing subscription with id {0} from {1}", item.SubscriptionID, reportUrl)
            rs.DeleteSubscription(item.SubscriptionID)
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", item.SubscriptionID, item.Active, item.LastExecuted, item.LastExecutedSpecified)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Now if you change the variables in the bat file and run the bat file it should remove all subscriptions that are older then 1 month this includes the actual sql job.

***Warning: This will remove jobs that run more then once so if you have a report scheduled to run once a year it will be lost!***